# How to find balance between overconfidence and lacking confidence?

Tags: conference, etiquette, computer-science, undergraduate

**Main Question:**

I am an undergraduate student who just attended my first conference and gave a podium talk on my research from last summer. I tried talking with a researcher who is well-known in the field about his views and he was rather dismissive.  I am not sure how I should have handled the situation at the time or in reflection.

On one hand, his view is likely shared by only a small minority of people in the field, the view that no machine learning should be used in healthcare unless it is explainable (as opposed to "black box" deep learning models). He proposes we should use methods such as symbolic logic AI instead (what he did most of his career).

On the other hand, I am just an undergraduate in the field and he is a very established researcher.  I would expect him to be more correct than me.

1. How should I view the interaction?  Should I assume I am probably wrong? Should I assume that he is wrong?  Another option...?
2. In the future, should I press the debate more rather than only asking a few questions and thanking him for the info?  Would this be impolite at a conference?  Would it be an unwise career move?

**Supplementary Info/Thoughts:**

I find this balance of overconfidence vs underconfidence confusing in general for academics.  Ranking myself compared to my peers is rather easy (I view myself near the top, but not an outlier). But comparing myself to people older than me is more difficult, particularly in situations where "wrongness" cannot be definitively proven.

Should I raise my disagreement when this occurs?  How long should I debate the issue if we don't agree?  If we don't agree in the end should I assume I'm wrong? It seems like senior researchers are likely to be correct. I am just not sure what to do/think when I disagree with established, senior researchers in fields such as health informatics.

If anyone would be interested in discussing symbolic AI vs ML in healthcare I would be glad to do it (in the chat).  I currently feel unresolved since I could not do it during the conference and would like to know what points I am failing to see.

Comment: How was he _rather dismissive_?

Comment: @xedg It's worth keeping in mind that this really is a limitation of current machine learning methods. It seems weird to single out healthcare applications though. Maybe you could have gotten an interesting reaction by asking if we should also refrain from using drugs if we don't know the mechanisms through which they work...

Comment: @Anyon Perhaps the use of machine learning in healthcare can be governed by existing legal frameworks, such as those used for drugs

Comment: @Anyon  I agree, and I tried to ask at what point could the empirical accuracy of a system outweigh the lack of explainability, but he said it should always be explainable and they are called "clincial decision **support** systems".  I did ask a question similar to yours as well.

Comment: @user2768 He said a few things that made me think he was being a little dismissive such as saying "I already mentioned it" even though I was asking for additional explanation, not a repetition.  He responded at one point by saying that systems shouldn't diagnose because "they are called clinical decision **support** systems not diagnosis systems".

Comment: In my experience this is not a minority opinion, and part of his dismissive stance may have stemmed from him having had this exact same discussion dozens of times before (due to current hype around deep learning).

Comment: @xLeitix I am aware that explainable machine learning is a research goal for many people.  However, the more extreme view that blackbox methods shouldn't be used for any task in healthcare at all seems uncommon to me.  Granted, I have not had that much exposure to the literature, so I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) How should I view the interaction? Should I assume I am probably wrong? Should I assume that he is wrong? Another option...?

**Researchers should have differing opinions on topics** such as whether non-explainable machine learning techniques should be used in healthcare.

> 2) In the future, should I press the debate more rather than only asking a few questions and thanking him for the info? Would this be impolite at a conference? Would it be an unwise career move?

**Such opinions should be debated**, that's how research advances, and such debate should be encouraged, at conferences and elsewhere. Some researchers will be less willing to accept your opinion than others, only you can decide whether you want to engage with such researchers.

> Should I raise my disagreement when this occurs?

If you want to.

> How long should I debate the issue if we don't agree?

As long as the conversation lasts.

> If we don't agree in the end should I assume I'm wrong?

No. There doesn't seem to be any right and wrong here, just opinions.

Comment: Could it be considered an opinion though if we share the same defined goal?  In other words, we can disagree what the best metrics of performance are, but one method will probably perform better than the other by the given metrics.

Comment: I also was at first under the impression that the point of conferences was to improve research through discussion.  However when I look at what the more senior researchers are doing, it seems more common for them to maybe ask a single question that hints at their disagreement and then leave it at that.  My adviser was saying he thought several studies were not very good, but I did not see him talk to the presenters at all.

Comment: @xedg I think you've already touched upon what I meant by opinion, e.g., with your _formal sciences_ remark. _the point of conferences was to improve research through discussion_, conferences have many _points_, it depends a little on the field. _ask[ing] a single question that hints at their disagreement and then leave it at that_ is perhaps a tactic to confirm their suspicion.

Answer (score 2):

xedg, there seems to be two issues here which seems to complicate your mixed feelings. One issue is around status, which you alluded to, with your first author publications and strong academic record. The second issue is around where is the best environment to debate and clarify the pros and cons around the role of machine learning.

The first issue around status is quite unfair as you positioned the professor as being disrespectful or "dismissive". First conference presentations are usually always given great courtesy especially in question time. So what you interpreted as dismissive, may possibly be respectful distance. You are also not in a PhD program or have not finished your PhD, so experts will always back off and not put you in difficult spots out of respect of your position despite your accomplished publication record - [common conference etiquette blog](https://danirabaiotti.wordpress.com/2017/05/15/academic-etiquette-tips-on-conducting-yourself-at-an-academic-conference/) Remember having a bad experience at a conference will look bad for the conference and may also discourage people who may want to do a PhD. Attacking junior researchers will also diminish the professor in the eyes of other senior experts. Making junior presenters cry has been a subject of discussion among experts and does not look good at all. So all these factors may explain why debating an undergrad is poor form at a conference question time post-presentation. The other possible issue is around familiarity. As you attend more conferences and become a familiar face, people will be far more comfortable debating and clarifying complex issues with you compared to your first conference.

The second issue is what is the most appropriate format for this debate. If you want to flesh out "the role of machine learning in healthcare" at a conference, the short question time post-presentation is definitely not an appropriate timeslot for such a complex discussion. Symposiums or panel discussions are far more a satisfying format with the appropriate adjudication and moderation for this to occur. A senior mathematician would have a very different perspective than a clinician for example, but in a panel format, all the views would be respected rather than just your narrow focus on what is "right or correct" as implied in your question.

A review article examining the pros and cons of symbolic logic AI as the dominant approach in healthcare then be more appropriate in an extended article, rather than at a conference? To expect an expert to synthesize his academic focus and all the publications in a field is unproductive and not representative in a short question timeslot post-presentation.

I liked this [Indian Hills presentation](http://www.indianhills.edu/_myhills/courses/ENG106/documents/lu09_argue.pdf) on how not to be argumentative might be helpful. Although you might not be overly argumentative, it always pays to move away from the "correct vs wrong" mentality in the academic realm. Most things are "more right" and "more wrong" depending on the scenario and circumstance.

Comment: Sorry I may have been unclear.  In the instance I talk about, I approached the senior researcher for clarification after the official question time had ended and people were conversing.  How much discussion is appropriate at this point in the conference?

Answer (score 0):

There is another issue here that hasn't yet been raised. It is an ethical issue. I don't think it is, in the present day, a small minority of people who believe, on ethical grounds, that it is improper to apply medical procedures to people if they can't be explained. It is actually experimentation that has fairly strict protocols around it. Even before you can begin an experiment on humans you need some "reason" that the procedure might be effective and strong reasons that it won't be harmful.

So, the population that holds this view might not be those doing "black box" machine learning, but it is pretty strong among medical people and ethicists. FWIW, I'm closer to your field than his.

I think that was the message being conveyed. And even I would convey it, though I'm certainly not an expert in clinical methods.

Oddly, however, lots of things that are done in medicine have a historical basis that leads to standard practice that has never been explained to the standards *of this time*. Yes, ten thousand years ago, people tried things (herbs, say) and if they seemed to work, they were used again, even if, in reality they had no real effect. But we aren't in those times anymore. Scientific medicine requires a cause-effect reasoning path. Shall we try some ground up rhinoceros horn as a cure for that? Ivermectin?

There are many known flaws in black-box ML. The results are no better than the data, and might be worse. The data can be bad because of poor sampling (inadequate, biased, ...) techniques.

I don't see your interaction of one of expert vs novice so much as pointing out to you the ethical considerations required in medicine. That isn't a reason to stop what you are doing, but it is a reason to situate it properly in the world of medical ethics.

A similar experience in a field without such strong ethical considerations might be completely different. The more experienced person may not always be correct in any case, but a novice should listen carefully and try to take the right lesson from it.